# re-assigning parameters

Tags: parameters, function

I've seen the following in legacy code:

```
public void someFunction(List myList){
List myList2 = myList;
}
```

Is there a good reason to re-assign parameters as local variables in a function?

Comment: This looks like Java or C#, so it must be some pretty new "legacy code"!

Comment: @Neil: the "legacy" label sticks pretty quickly, and Java is 14 years old.

Comment: Yes, it's java code.  Thanks for all the answers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. Aliasing or reuse of names should be avoided, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a personal style. Or a failed attempt to create a new reference? I am pretty sure as-is the compiler discards myList2 in favor of myList.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language. In some cases, you may want to make changes to the "copy" later on - and in some languages/situations changing the original parameter will make changes to what the caller sees.

If you could say which language you're talking about (Java?) and give a concrete example, that would help us to explain.

Answer (score 0):

There's no good reason to do this, with pass-by-value parameters.  This looks like a not-quite-fluent developer, recalling that another language he's worked with bit him if he didn't work on copies of his parameters.